# validate integers for certain values in java

Tags: java, validation

I'm trying to verify that users input only 1, 2, or 3. So far I've used sc.hasNextInt() to validate integers, but not those specific ones. Can someone help? My code is below.

```
System.out.print("Enter Department Number: ");
while (!sc.hasNextInt())                
{
    System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please enter 1, 2, or 3 for the         
                       department number.");
    System.out.print("Enter Department Number: ");                
    sc.next();
}
int department =  (sc.nextInt());
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not account for a String-to-Int Conversion or the newLine character left unconsumed.

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

   int choice = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine().trim());
   if (choice == 1 || choice == 2 || choice == 3)
      //do something

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be:

```
System.out.print("Enter Department Number: ");
int department =  sc.nextInt();    
while(department != 1 || department != 2 || department != 3 ) {
  System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please enter 1, 2, or 3 for the         
                       department number.");
  System.out.print("Enter Department Number: ");                
  department = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: this throws me a system error if i enter a non-numeric value and endlessly loops the code if i do enter a numeric.

Comment: you can use `sc.next()` if you want to enter a `String` and use `Integer.parseInt()` to parse it to an `int`. The above code is just one way of doing it, you can use `String` if you want although you will have to handle them

Answer (score 0):

Read entire line and check that it matches regular expression:

```
int department;

System.out.print("Enter Department Number: ");
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    if (line.matches("[123]")) {
        System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please enter 1, 2, or 3 for the department number.");
        System.out.print("Enter Department Number: ");
    } else {
        department = Integer.parseInt(line);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop where you ask for the next integer and only break when it is inside the correct range:

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int value;
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter Department Number: ");
        if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            value = sc.nextInt();
            if (value < 1 || value > 3)
                System.out
                        .println("Invalid entry... must be between 1 and 3");
            else
                break;
        }
    }
    else
        sc.next(); // does not block when a string is putted in
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very clean or coherent but

```
int input;
while(!sc.hasNextInt()||((input=sc.nextInt())>3&&input<1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int departement;

do {
   System.out.print("Enter Department Number: ");
   departement = sc.nextInt();
}while (departement != 1 && departement != 2 && departement != 3);
```